# Setting image position with javascript, not always placing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to position images on my page:

```
var adjustImages = function(){
    var monsters = [$("#m3"), $("#m4")];

    monsters[0].css('right', monsters[0].width() * -0.4 + "px");
    monsters[0].css('top', $("#divider-green").height() + $("#divider-orange").height() + (monsters[3].height() / 6) + "px");
    monsters[1].css('left', monsters[1].width() * -0.385 + "px");
    monsters[1].css('top', $("#divider-green").height() + $("#divider-orange").height() + $("#divider-red").height() + "px");
}
```

I'm then calling this function when the page loads, and when it's resized:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    adjustImages();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    adjustImages();
};
```

The images are meant to be positioned on the window border (as in, part of the image is off the screen, part it off). This is done by setting right/left to a negative number (relative to the image size).

Sometimes when I refresh the page the images are placed correctly, however other times they are not over the border (but are rather positioned against the border (as if no left/right adjustment was applied). Does anyone know what the cause of this might be?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the images haven't loaded yet.

Comment: I tried calling adjustImages() when they all load (using onload), and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: this can be made just using css, by the way...  You need to wait the image loading and resolve some issues, like: `monsters[3]` while your array has length of 2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't doing any check to see if the image is loaded before doing math based on it's width. That's probably what's causing the inconsistent behavior.

When an image is first created in the DOM, before it's loaded (and if it doesn't have one set directly), it's width and height are 0. What I would do is add a `load` event listener on your images and then call adjust.

You also want to call `adjustImages()` if one of the images already has a width greater than 0, because that means it's already loaded by the time the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#m3, #m4').one('load', function () {
        adjustImages();
    });

    if ($('#m3').width > 0 || $('#m4').width > 0) {
        adjustImages();
    }
});
```

Now, that code snippet has a bit of a bug because it'll fire once either is loaded, not when both are loaded. You'll want to tweak it, and probably even separate them out so you're doing things individually for each, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: It's not letting me use .once, getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).once is not a function(…)

Comment: @Fianite Sorry, it's `.one` not `.once`